# node.js ParseError - which file is the error thrown in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error, try-catch

I've got quite a big library written in node.js, too big to paste here (>20 files). I've got a try..catch that catches the error, I debug the catch part and I console.log the error as below:

`{ [ParseError: value.key.split is not a function]
  message: 'value.key.split is not a function',
  path: [ 'properties', 'statement1' ],
  name: 'ParseError' }`

The thing is - I don't know which file is that and I'm somehow unable to debug it. Can I access the source file (line, preferably) where this error was thrown? What node.js returns is the actual line that it tried to execute, but I can hardly spot where it is... Any suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
console.dir( error );
```

on error instead. You also might try logging the `stack` property explicitly:

```
console.log( error.stack );
```